# Google PlayStore publishing

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I'm registered at google playstore developers panel. I payed 25$ and everything. Only thing that has left is that i need to register to google checkout merchant but on registration form I'm asked to fill in company informations. Problem is that i want to sell my game as the person not as a company. Is that impossible?

If is can someone tell me some alternatives like publishers? Maybe give me a list of trusted ones? Any help would be great :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah--you can absolutely enter a person's name for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a company name. This is the name that will be displayed under your application in the market, and you can always change it later.

Have a look here:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=m3bohg8w3bmo

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en